# How to remove spaces and newlines in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, replace, trim

sorry if they are not very practical for C # Asp.Net, I hope to make me understand
I have this situation

```
string content = ClearHTMLTags(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Body));
content=content.Replace("\r\n", "");
content=content.Trim();
((Post)sender).Description = content + "...";
```

I would make sure that the string does not contain content nor spaces (Trim) and neither carriage return with line feed, I'm using the above code inserted but it does not work great either

any suggestions??

Thank you very much
Fabry

Comment: Explain "does not work great", show example input and output.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can remove all whitespaces with this regex

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"\s+", string.Empty);
```

what are whitespace characters from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664665%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Btw you are mistaking `Trim` with removing spaces, in fact it's only removing spaces at the begining and at the end of string. If you want to replace all spaces and carige returns use my regex.

Comment: Work Perfectly... i replaced String.Empty with " ", for give a space between a word and the other.

Answer (score 6):

this should do it

```
String text = @"hdjhsjhsdcj/sjksdc\t\r\n asdf";

        string[] charactersToReplace = new string[] { @"\t", @"\n", @"\r", " " };
        foreach (string s in charactersToReplace)
        {
            text = text.Replace(s, "");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

simple change only you missed @ symbol

```
string content = ClearHTMLTags(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Body));
content=content.Replace(@"\r\n", "");
content=content.Trim();
((Post)sender).Description = content + "...";
```